# Mouse Double Hover With CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a problem with this code, I try to code this two objects get hover together and  I have images and code below.

When mouse hover circle icon rectangle shape has appear (Step 1) and i need to hover rectangle shape and circle icon has hover too (Step 2).

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqX2w.png)
[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xfcZ.png)

I try this with css code.

.GoToPage1 //Circle icon

.GoToPage2 //Rectangle shape

```
.GoToPage1 {
cursor: pointer;
width: 40px !important;
height: 40px !important;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background: #0F283E url('/file/serve/6205609736798208');
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-position: center center;
border-radius: 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
transition: box-shadow .3s, background-color .3s;
}

.GoToPage1-up-hovering:hover {
    background-image: url(/file/serve/6383691428921344);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #0F283E;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.GoToPage1-up-hovering:hover + .GoToPage2_Rectangle {
    border-color: #FF0000;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s, color 0.3s,;
}

.GoToPage2_Rectangle  {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s, color 0.3s,;
}

.GoToPage2_Rectangle-up-hovering:hover  {
   /* background-image: url(/file/serve/5419025936547840);
*/  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s, color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.GoToPage2_Rectangle-up-hovering:hover + .GoToPage1 {
    background-image: url(/file/serve/6383691428921344);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
  /*border-color: #ff0000;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s, color 0.3s,;
*/}
```